# Selecting from decimal (18,6) return NaN in pandas using Teradata python library

Tags: python, type-conversion, decimal, teradata

Evn: Python 3.6, windows 10,

Connection:

```
connect = udaExec.connect(
    method="odbc",
    system='***',
    username= username,
    password= password,
    driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10",
    dataTypeConverter=datatypes.DefaultDataTypeConverter(
                    useFloat=False) #tried setting to True - same results
)



query = 'sel top 1 MNQ from tb1'
pd.read_sql(query, connect) #this return NaNs as result
```

`read_sql` - has `coerce_float` param - changing from default True to False - nothing changed

How to fix this? Link to github `issue`

Comment: Not a solution, per say, but have you tried an explicit cast to float in the SELECT statement? `SELECT TOP 1 CAST(MNQ AS FLOAT) FROM tb1;`  Just to see if you can eliminate the NaN.

Comment: @RobPaller yep it worked

Comment: There was a problem tracked on Github related to DECIMAL data types. I don’t know if that is what you encountered here or not, but I am glad you found a different route to a solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to admit - teradata library is wasted and longer supported. My problem easily fixed my using another library:

```
from turbodbc import connect
driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.10"
connection = connect(driver=driver,
                      server=ip, 
                      DBCName='.com', 
                      uid=username,
                      pwd=password)

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = 'sel * from tb'
cursor.execute(query)
data = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchallnumpy()) #to get pandas dataframe
data.to_csv('tb.csv')
cursor.close()
```